# Java streams, trying to turn a Map<String, List<T>> into a Map<String, Map<String, List<T>>>

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

So I have the following object:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications {

    private StakeholderTypeEntity stakeholderTypeEntity;
    private StakeholderDepartmentEntity stakeholderDepartmentEntity;
    private StakeholderEntity stakeholderEntity;
    private StakeholderNotificationEntity stakeholderNotificationEntity;
}
```

So I initially had a list of this object, and I turned it into a `Map<String, List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>` where the key is `stakeholderDepartmentEntity.getId()`:

```
Map<String, List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>> map =
    stakeholders.stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity() != null)
                .collect(groupingBy(
                        entry -> entry.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity().getId()));
```

However now I would like the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>>
```

Where the key of the top level map is `stakeholderTypeEntity.getId()`, where the value is the Map from above, where the key is the `stakeholderDepartmentEntity.getId()`

Comment: I don't understand the problem, you want to change the previous `Map` to new `Map` by java stream? Or do you want to create new `Map` by streaming the previous `Map`?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using another `groupingBy` as a downstream collector:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>>> resultMap = 
    stakeholders
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getStakeholderTypeEntity() != null)
            .filter(e -> e.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    e -> e.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity().getId(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                        e -> e.getStakeholderTypeEntity().getId())));
```

Of course, an additional check whether `getStakeholderTypeEntity()` doesn't return `null` might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>>> result = stakeholders
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getStakeholderTypeEntity() != null && 
                 e.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity() != null)
    .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getStakeholderTypeEntity().getId(), 
             groupingBy(e -> e.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity().getId())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by applying `Collectors.groupingBy` several times:

```java
Map<String, Map<String,List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>>> result = 
    stakeholders
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> Objects.nonNull(entry.getStakeholderTypeEntity())
            && Objects.nonNull(entry.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity()))
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                entry -> entry.getStakeholderTypeEntity().getId(),
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                    entry -> entry.getStakeholderDepartmentEntity().getId()
                )
            )
        );
```

---

Aside comment: it's worth to refactor the names of the fields to remove redundant verbosity:

```java
public class StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications {
    // just a model for an sql query that joins across all these tables
    private StakeholderTypeEntity type;
    private StakeholderDepartmentEntity department;
    private StakeholderEntity stakeholder;
    private StakeholderNotificationEntity notification;
}
```

Then building the map would look as follows:

```java
Map<String, Map<String,List<StakeHolderTypesDepartmentsNotifications>>> result = 
    stakeholders
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> Objects.nonNull(entry.getType()) && Objects.nonNull(entry.getDepartment()))
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                entry -> entry.getType().getId(),
                Collectors.groupingBy(-> entry.getDepartment().getId())
            )
        );
```